# In Google Analytics direct traffic has only 12% of returning users. How could it be?

Tags: seo, google, google-analytics

For quite a long time (at least a year), the statistics of our site is very stable: **more than half of the site’s traffic is Organic**, with 16% of returning users (the average for the entire site is 14%).

**In the second place is Direct traffic**. When we exclude the homepage as a landing page from this statistics, **the returning users is only 12%**. We don't do any bulk mailing, so **we think Direct traffic should mainly consist of returning users**.

Can someone explain why there are so few returning users in Direct traffic?

Comment: See also [Google analytics direct traffic report](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/17096/google-analytics-direct-traffic-report) which has a few reasons that visitors reported as "direct" may not actually be type in traffic.  More evidence: [Experiment Shows Up To 60% Of "Direct" Traffic Is Actually Organic Search - Search Engine Land](https://searchengineland.com/60-direct-traffic-actually-seo-195415)

Comment: As far as how GA measures returning users see: [How does Google Analytics define a new vs returning user?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/87522/how-does-google-analytics-define-a-new-vs-returning-user)